# QtWebEngine for Windows XP target

Tags: build, windows-xp, qtwebengine

I was trying to build Qt5.5 to be able to run QtWebEngine on Windows XP.
Here's my bat file to setup environment:

```
REM Set up \Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, where <arch> is \c amd64, \c x86, etc.
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
SET _ROOT=%CD%
SET PATH=%_ROOT%\qtbase\bin;C:\Perl\bin;%_ROOT%\gnuwin32\bin;C:\devtools\Bitnami\rubystack-2.0.0-26\ruby\bin;C:\Python27;%PATH%
REM Uncomment the below line when using a git checkout of the source repository
REM SET PATH=%_ROOT%\qtrepotools\bin;%PATH%
SET QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2013
SET _ROOT=
```

bat file to configure build

```
configure -debug-and-release -nomake examples -opensource -nomake tests -target xp -prefix c:\qt5\5.5\msvc2013-winxp
```

Build successfull, but I was unable to run any example with QtWebEngine[image]

Is it possible to build QtWebEngine for WinXP target or it incompatible with WinXP?

Answer (score 7):

Qt WebEngine 5.5.0 for Windows XP compatibility build steps

**PROBLEM WITH OFFICIAL RELEASE**

Qt 5.5.0 oficial release qwebengine module is incompatible with Windows XP applications, even if you force your project binary with XP compatibility compilation/linking settings/flags(QT DLLs are probably still incompatible) and you can exec your exe binary file under XP, you can't use qwebengine module anyway- just because QtWebEnbineProcess.exe is build as invalid EXE for windows XP.

To make Qt WebEngine 5.5.0 possible to run on winXP you must rebuild Qt modules with additional options way (as as said oficial Qt release is incompatible at all, you must build new one). Under Windows QtWebEngine can be only build only in Visual Studio 2013, there is no possible to build chromium code in another version of Visual Studio. Normally Qt and chromium under Windows can be build with using OpenGL or/and ANGLE project(which uses Direc3D9Ex or Direct3D11) support for hardware graphics operations, if you build for WinXP you have no choose, you must use OpenGL(which is worst choise, if you have choise), because Direct3D9Ex/Direct3D11 are available to install only from Vista+. So make sure you have installed updated  graphics drivers for machine where will run your program, because stock XP drivers for your card for OpenGL will be very outdated and perhaps won't work valid.

**PROBLEM GENESIS**

Any problems occur just because default Visual C++ 2013 app compilation is incompatible with XP(C runtime and EXE subsystem), but you can still change and use runtime compatible with WinXP in Visual C++ 2013, this is described there:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx

so basicly you must add Windows SDK7.1A paths to include, libs and binaries, pass /D_USING_V120_SDK71_ for every cl compiler execution for Qt and chromium and pass /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01 or /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.01 for linker invocations while build your project and QtWebEngineProcess.exe, simple isn't it :)

**Build requirements:**

1. Visual C++ 2013 (in my case installed in stardard location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0)
2. Windows SDK 7.1A - last Windows XP compatible SDK, /D_USING_V120_SDK71_ forces to use it (in my case installed in standard location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A)
3. 3rd party tools, used to build chromium: Git, Perl, Python, pscp.exe- you must add their binaries to PATH env variable before build.
4. OpenGL ES SDK to use OpenGL ES 2.0 implementation, I downloaded from AMD (in my case donwloaded to D:\rzaba\qt\GLES_SDK).
5. Qt 5.5.0 sources- unpacked to D:\rzaba\qt\src-5.5.0

(I can't paste more links because I don't have 2 points reputation, OMG! :D)

**Build process**

First read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html, we must do this like there, but few more step is need for XP compatible build.

Now if source code is unpacked and everything is installed create qt5vars.cmd, in my case it looks like this:

```
************************************************************************
REM ********** INITIALIZE ENV FOR MSVC 2013 CL COMPILER **********
SET PATH=C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
REM ********** UPDATE INCLUDE & LIB TO SUPPORT XP WIN SDK 7.1A **********
SET PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin;%PATH%
SET INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include;%INCLUDE%
SET LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib;%LIB%
SET CL=/D_USING_V120_SDK71_;%CL%
REM ********** INCLUDE OPENGL DESKTOP GLES SDK **********
SET PATH=D:\rzaba\qt\GLES_SDK\x86;%PATH%
SET INCLUDE=D:\rzaba\qt\GLES_SDK\include;%INCLUDE%
SET LIB=D:\rzaba\qt\GLES_SDK\x86;%LIB%
REM ********** 3D PARTY BUILD TOOLS BINARIES: PUTTY, RUBY, PERL, GIT, PYTHON ********** 
SET PATH=D:\putty;D:\Ruby22\bin;D:\Perl\bin;D:\Git;D:\Git\bin;D:\Git\cmd;D:\Python27;%PATH%
REM ********** SETUP QT QMAKE ENV **********
SET QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2013
SET PATH=D:\rzaba\qt\src-5.5.0\qtbase\bin;D:\rzaba\qt\src-5.5.0\gnuwin32\bin;%PATH%
************************************************************************
```

Generally script configures PATH, INCLUDE, LIB env variables for build. In CL env variable can force CL compiler setting, this is main place where we define V120_XP platform usage.

Now before you start build you must edit some files from sources:

1. you must edit file: qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\ninja\configure.py
   find line with: "if platform.is_msvc():" and there you have cl compiler flags, you must remove '/WX' flag, becuse it will fails compilation for sdk7.1. You can also add there '/D_USING_V120_SDK71_' flag, to make sure ninja tool will also define to use V120_xp.
2. and you must edit another file: qtwebengine\src\process\process.pro and add there those lines:

win32: {

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /D_USING_V120_SDK71

QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE += /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.1

QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS += /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.1

}

you should also add this into your project. This will generate QtWebEngineProcess.exe file compatible with XP. Without this Visual C++ 2013 builds invalid EXE file for winXP.

If you open command line and call this script now you must cd to qt source directory and call configure, this is my configuration:

**configure -prefix d:[your install path there] -confirm-license -target xp -opensource -opengl desktop -debug-and-release -nomake examples -nomake tests -no-warnings-are-errors**

So I want build debug and release. If you setup everything correctly you should see some compilation process and create Makefiles for qt modules.
After that call nmake, compilation makes few hours, and nmake install to copy/install created libraries to prefix.
Good luck

Remember that graphics device must support OpenGL ES 2.0, otherwise after creation QWebView your app will crash by OpenGL driver, or window GUI becomes black. If you want run your app on old machine, you can build Mesa OpenGL software render(I did it and performance is rly slow, few seconds per any refresh window GUI content, but it works) and use it instead hardware driver.

Comment: You have written in the *.pro file:
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /D_USING_V120_SDK71. But where is the last underscore /D_USING_V120_SDK71_? Also, I've met the following instruction QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS = /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01 on the other site. (1) So, which version should I choose - 5.01 or 5.1? (2) Where should I set `--single-process` if I'd like to debug my program which implicitly calls QtWebEngineProcess.exe? (3) Which 3rd party dlls do I have to deploy (e.g. OpenGL ES SDK)? (4) Is debug version of program able to work with QtWebEngineProcess.exe (mixing release and debug Qt dlls in 1 folder)?

Comment: Please, add explicit info that this engine does not work with XP since Qt 5.6 :( https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49900

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the compiler from Visual Studio 2013, but the headers/libraries from a Windows SDK supporting Windows XP (that's 7.1A):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include;%INCLUDE%
set LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib;%LIB%
set CL=/D_USING_V110_SDK71_
```

Note though that QtWebEngine requires a working Qt Quick stack (even QtWebEngineWidgets!), which in turn requires OpenGL. Because OpenGL support on a stock Windows XP is close to non-existent, and ANGLE (the DirectX wrapper) is not working on Windows XP, you need either to make sure there's a decent 3rd party OpenGL driver installed, or fall back to a software opengl32.dll (e.g. from mesa). If you've a Qt license you can also rely on the Qt Quick 2d renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Just open qtwebengine\src\process\process.pro with vs2013, modify to "Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)" an rebuild QtWebEngineProcess.exe